# DROID 4 ADB Driver for Linux

Tags: rooting, motorola-droid

I'm trying to unlock my phone using [this](http://www.andromods.com/root-unlock/xt894-vzw-droid-4-9872188-rooted-latest-ota.html) tutorial.
It stated that:

Prerequisites

- A computer with DROID 4 adb [drivers installed](http://www.andromods.com/download-files/install-moto-x-usb-drivers-latest-version.html). [alternate link](http://www.teamandroid.com/2014/12/15/moto-x-2014-usb-drivers-download/)
- Enable USB Debugging on your device by going to Developers options.
- Download RAZR BLADE exploit by [djrbliss](http://d-h.st/YUJ) from here.

But there are no Linux driver, or is it not needed for Linux?

Why I need this?
because I need to [remove /system/app/VZWPhoneService.apk and /system/app/VZWPhoneService.odex. then reboot.](http://www.droidrzr.com/topic/7616-sim-card-from-an-unknown-source-error/?p=432494), because the other way already [expired](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/87243/using-non-verizon-sim-on-motorola-xt912-verizon-phone). So I could use this phone using another carrier.

The [alternate method](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2166542) also requires Windows OS.

Comment: If your device is getting detected by ADB in your Linux box, then you don't need a driver. Well we don't really need a driver most of the time to detect a phone in a Linux PC. Just some UDEV rules sometimes for further interaction. There is a .zip file in that tutorial for exploit. It has a .bat file and .exe as well. You'll have to move the content of the .bat file to a .sh and provide the necessary files to it (if the script depends on them). I believe the approach should work.

Comment: You're right, it works out of the box, just need `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your device is rooted there is a ppa for adb and fastboot.

Type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogardwebupd8

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

Now you should open a shell/rootshell and type

```
adb
```

followed by

```
adb devices
```

Then your Phone should show up. To delete the app and odex file type:

```
adb rm /path/to/apk

adb rm /path/to/file
```

or

```
adb uninstall [-k] packagename
```

The option -k keeps cache and data on your phone if you want to.

Then end this process by using

```
adb reboot
```

Cheers

Comment: OP is trying to root the device which can be confirmed from the very first link: http://www.andromods.com/root-unlock/xt894-vzw-droid-4-9872188-rooted-latest-ota.html What's the point in this answer then? Please explain.